# PyTorch forward pass speed depending on variables

Tags: machine-learning, time, deep-learning, pytorch

Why does the time to forward pass through the MLP model depend on the size of an input data (before sampling and creating a smaller batch)?

For instance, if I select 10 (batch size) data from original dataset of size 100 (whole data size), the time required for forward pass should not depend on 100, rather depend on 10.

I have figured out that when I increase the size of a batch, the forward pass time also increases. However, same thing happens when I increase the number of the total dataset.

I have a model that trains over a certain batch size of inputs (in this case 100) which is sampled from consecutive integer array that has a form of,

```py
# Generate input
time0 = time.time()

input_data = np.zeros([n,1]).astype(np.float64)

for i in range(len(input_array)):
    input_data[i, 0] = -1.5 + 3 / (n-1) * i

time1 = time.time()



# Train
batchSize = 100

for train_step in range(1000):
   indexTotal = [num for num in range(n)]
   batchIndices = random.sample(indexTotal, batchSize)
   input_data_0 = input_data[batchIndices, :] # Sample data

   input_data_combined = np.concatenate([input_data_0] * 3, axis=0) # Combine data
   input_data_combined = input_data_combined + shiftMat # Add bias
   input_data_combined = torch.tensor(input_data_combined, requires_grad=True, device=device) # Convert to tensor
   time2 = time.time()

   output_combined = model(input_data_combined) # Forward pass
   time3 = time.time()
   
   # Back propagation
```

Basically it combines multiple numpy arrays into a single array, adds a bias (also a numpy array) to it, and forwards to the model. The model is a simple MLP model with a condition where if it receives tensor that is within certain boundary it returns zero.

```py
# Define neural network
class myModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 31) # (x, y) input
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(31, 31)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(31, 1) 

    def forward(self, x):
        # Check if each row is close to [1.1, 0] within epsilon (=0.01)
        epsilon = 0.01
        isClose2Target = torch.all(torch.abs(x - torch.tensor([1.1, 0], device=device)) < epsilon, dim=1)
        
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.tanh(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = torch.tanh(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)

        # Set the output to 0 for rows that are close to [1.1, 0]
        x[isClose2Target] = torch.tensor([0])

        return x # Single Eb output
```

If I increase the batchSize, time required for forward pass increases. Current problem is that forward pass time also increases if I increase `n` (size of a full dataset), which does not make sense (since the model received input size of `batchSize`, not `n`).

I presume it might be the problem with `random.sample()` function where it may store the information about n but I am not sure...

Which part of the code may cause this problem?

I tried on both GPU and CPU but they both gave me the same result where the forward pass speed depends on both `n` and `batchSize`.

I am currently measuring time using time module, `time.time()` as written inside the code above.

I also found out another example that shows the effect of using random.sample() function. Following is the code:

timeForward = 0
for i in range(100):
# Sample batch indices
indexTotal = [num for num in range(n**dim)]
indexTotal = indexTotal[0:(n**1)*end[0]+(n**0)*end[1]] + indexTotal[(n**1)*end[0]+(n**0)*end[1]+1:n**dim]
batchIndices = random.sample(indexTotal, batchSize) # Never sample i=N (end state)

```
input_data_0 = np.ones([batchSize, 2])



input_data_combined = torch.tensor(input_data_0, requires_grad=True, device=device)



# Model output
time0 = time.time()
output_combined = model(input_data_combined)
time1 = time.time()



# Update time
timeForward = timeForward + time1 - time0
```

The input, which is input_data_0 has nothing to do with variable n nor sampling process. However, if we increase n from 10 to 61, we can see that the time (only for forward pass) timeForward also increases.

Image of time to n

Interesting thing is that if we delete the line where random sampling takes place (modified code as below):

timeForward = 0
for i in range(100):
input_data_0 = np.ones([batchSize, 2])

```
input_data_combined = torch.tensor(input_data_0, requires_grad=True, device=device)



# Model output
time0 = time.time()
output_combined = model(input_data_combined)
time1 = time.time()



# Update time
timeForward = timeForward + time1 - time0
```

it shows no dependency of time respect to n:

Image of time to n - modified

Is this a problem with python module time?

Comment: How large does `n` tend to be?

Comment: n I am using now ranges from 1000 to 5000.